# OBIEE Concatenate on null values

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, obiee

I am trying to concatenate two columns in OBIEE prompts using pipes (||" "||) and it works but the problem is that one table has more rows and I want to eliminate the extra rows:

**Here is an example:**

```
Col A    |  Col B
---------+---------
abcdefgh | ijklmn  
opqrstuv |           ** Remove these ones **  
wxyz123  | anything
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Why don't you just filter the whole analysis for Col B IS NOT NULL?

Comment: You want the row to not show up at all?